# Do ETFs suffer dilution like shares?

Tags: stocks

Can an issuing company of an ETF decide to offer more units to the market to raise cash? If not, then how does it expand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ETF is a fund that holds other securities. The value of the ETF shares should be close to the value of the constituent shares. A common mechanism to ensure this is a creation/redemption process through which authorized participants such as market makers can create new ETF shares or convert ETF shares into other assets.

The ETF will usually post a basket of securities they would like to get. Someone else can give this basket to the ETF and get a block of shares of equivalent value instead. Small differences between the value can be settled in cash. And in the other direction, someone can return some ETF shares to the ETF, and get a basket of the ETF's assets of equivalent value instead.

So this process merely exchanges shares at the same value, it doesn't dilute the value of ETF shares. For every $1 in shares created by the ETF, the ETF will receive other assets at that value and thus grow by that value. ETFs are generally open-ended funds.

Of course, the ETF value might diverge slightly from the value of the basket. This presents an arbitrage opportunity. If the ETF shares are more expensive than the basket of assets, someone will create new ETF shares for those cheaper assets, increasing supply of the ETF shares and lowering the price. And if the ETF shares are too cheap, someone will buy them in order to convert them into the more valuable assets, increasing demand for the ETF and raising the price.

Comment: Two short questions: 1) "increasing supply of the ETF shares" thru direct offering is it? 2) can you redeem as fractional shares? Thank you

Comment: @KaguyaŌtsutsuki 1) The authorized participant who created new shares with the ETF can then sell them on an exchange. 2) Fractional shares are offered by some brokers but cannot be traded on an exchange and are not relevant here. The ETF share creation/redemption process usually involves large blocks of shares worth around $10k in order to be worth the effort. This process is only accessible to authorized participants such as market makers, not to retail investors.